Duplicate the Google sheet workbook and rename the sheet as per input value app script code
I have A Google Sheets file, where I am having 2 workbooks One is Names and another one is Data
I have the below code which duplicates the workbook and rename the workbook  name as the value of last column as workbook name. In Names workbook sheet I have A1 to A181 data. I want the Data sheet to be duplicate by 181 times and the workbook sheet name should be changed according to the value of A1:A181 of Name Sheet.
function Duplicate() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
 var myValue = ss1.getRange(1, 1, 1, ss1.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues()[0].filter(String).pop();
ss.renameActiveSheet(myValue);
}

Also in the new sheet I want B2=name of the sheet
Google Sheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XTPFuYusDyffbTucYGZH0wi9uSTnUfGrUOwW1OuGg4w/edit?usp=sharing

When I saw your provided Spreadsheet, the template sheet had 23 columns and 4102 rows. From I want the Data sheet to be duplicate by 181 times, in this case, 23 x 4102 x 181 = 17,076,626. Also, you have other sheets. In this case, the number of cells is over 10,000,000 which is the maximum number of cells in a Spreadsheet. Also, even when the total number of cells is nearly 10,000,000, the process cost of the script for processing it is very high. So, I'm worried that you might be required to modify your goal. How about this?

To process all names and create as many copies of the template sheet, you need a loop.
The Spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet() method duplicates the active sheet and makes the new sheet the active sheet. For simplicity, use Sheet.copyTo(), like this:
function duplicateTemplate() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const names = ss.getRange('Names!A1:A').getValues().flat().filter(String);
  const template = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
  names.forEach(name => {
    const sheet = template.copyTo(ss);
    try {
      sheet.setName(name);
    } catch (error) {
      ss.toast(error.message);
      Utilities.sleep(1000);
    }
    sheet.getRange('B2').setValue(name);
  });
}

See Sheet.copyTo().
